# Use same list in less and in scss

Tags: sass, less

In a project, I have quite a big list that stores various settings for different items. In `scss` I then loop over all the items of that list to generate different css code.

We would now like to include a `less` version to the project package so that every user can decide himself which preprocessor he uses. The problem is, that we would have to copy that huge list and translate it into `less`.

This is not very maintainable, so I'm wondering if there is a possibility to write a list in a format that can be read by both, `scss` and `less`.

---

```
$exampleList: (
    (foo1, bar1, lorem1, ipsum1, ...),
    (foo2, bar2, lorem2, ipsum2, ...),
    .
    .
    .
)

@each $foo, $bar, $lorem, $ipsum, $... in $exampleList {
    // Code
}
```

Comment: *so that every user can decide himself which preprocessor he uses* - Don't. This automatically implies your project is downgrading to use only a silly narrowed subset of both languages (= "CSS with variables" which by now is better to do with pure CSS).

Comment: I wouldn't see it as a downgrade. People use preprocessors in there projects which is great. Having the ability to import our code to your project files and change the variables to your needs is cool I think. FontAwesome for example does the same thing. Would you say that that's silly? I clearly don't!

Comment: You did not get it. Realize these are two *different* languages, they have something in common but even very basic things there are different. So to provide your project in both variants you'll have *stop* using any features of either language beyond the very limited subset. This is the downgrade (so instead of gaining a new users from the other language your in fact will loose many users of your project primary language, because alternative projects go better in use by not-limiting itself for the sake of multilanguage ports).

Comment: FontAwesome is popular only in its CSS form (and because  of its *icons*). Its SCSS/Less source-code is [extremely dumb](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/v4.7.0/less/icons.less) and a nightmare in reuse.

Comment: I know that we are talking about two different languages here, but that's not the point. The question was how I could use one array in both languages. A task that is done day by day in other languages. Your argument, that it does not make sense to offer a `less` and a `scss` version isn't valid either. Both are only `css` preprocessors and thus are pretty much capable of the same things, even if they are solved in a different manner. People using `less` in their projects would be happy to include our `less` source and vice versa.

Comment: Also I don't think, that the `less`/`scss` code of FontAwesome is "extremely dumb". Many developers want to provide a single stylesheet including all the used stuff, so having the possibility to include the FA code into your existing `scss`/`less` is very convenient. Moreover, this gives you the possibility to change the default path to the icon fonts which is quite nice too. Seems like we have a very different approach to these things, which is ok I think. Unfortunately, your answer is not very helpful as it has nothing to do with the problem itself.

Comment: *Unfortunately, your answer is not very helpful* my intention was only to give a remark on you falling into a common myth/trap. I did not write any answer.